# How to auto load the large database values into listview using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have an app where I load database values into listview (multiple columns) using SimpleCursorAdapter. The problem is that the data is increasing everyday and the app clearly lags to load this entire data at one go into listview.

I have done a lot of Google for this, found many solutions (some using `AsyncTasks` and some using `OnScrollListener` events) but I am just unable to implement these using SimpleCursorAdapter

Any pointer here (specific to `SimpleCursorAdapter`) would be a really great. may be a simplest possible code snippet would be highly appreciated

Here is what I do to get data into listview,

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    cursor = getDBData(sql); // this is causing the lag
    String[] col = new String[] { "col1", "col2", "col3"};

    int[] ids = new int[] { R.id.item_col1, R.id.item_col2, R.id.item_col3};

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, col, ids);

    list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

Comment: So how are you actually doing your query?

Comment: I have updated the question on how I use the adapter @ianhanniballake

Comment: Are you still working on this? Would you like to read a good tutorial to start?

Comment: You could load a chunk of data at a time. And when the user past the bottom row of the listview, you could load more data. This is my answer below.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Yes I am still working on this, please do share the links if there good tutorials (specific to simpleCursorAdapters)

Comment: I posted an answer but you'll have to tell me or us what you're doing now so that we can guide you better. You may respond to my posted answer and others.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I am still putting things together, could not reach to a solution yet. Will update you soon on this

Answer (score 0):

Use [LoaderManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html).

The way I have it set up is have `setAdapter()` called in `onCreate()` where you set up the adapter. In `onResume()` like you have, initiate or restart the loader.

```
if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(SOME_ID) != null)
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(SOME_ID, null, this);
        else
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(SOME_ID, null, this);
```

The docs will give you a good idea of how to set up the loader and get it into your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can load several database data at a time onto the ListView. When the user is viewing data, then you can get more data from the database. You will have to manage the data when user past the bottom row (position) on the ListView. You can manage this with `getView` or `bindView`. In getView, the user may not realize your app is getting more data from database. If this works well, then only one thread is running!

If any help, the CursorAdapter class has method `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` to execute a database query while the user is viewing the data, there will be 2 threads running.
I hope all is clear.

FYI: I have not reached this problem yet but I might. So I am interested on your solution as well as other suggestions.